# How Wunderlist created a search control in the window's title bar?

Tags: macos, cocoa, wunderlist

If you check Wunderlist for Mac OS X:

[image: Wunderlist]

You will see that there is a search control in the application's title bar.

How to create something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using something like [`INAppStoreWindow`](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/inappstorewindow) and a search control in the toolbar?

That should come pretty close.

Answer (score 3):

We are actually using INAppStoreWindow as mentioned above :)

Comment: Would you please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822458/position-the-search-box-at-the-left-of-the-title-bar :)