# Position the search box at the left of the title bar

Tags: macos, cocoa, fullscreen, appkit

I'm using [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) for my application. I put an `NSSearchButton` in the title bar of the application.

```
INAppStoreWindow *aWindow = (INAppStoreWindow*)self.window;
aWindow.titleBarHeight = 60.0;
aWindow.showsTitle = YES;

NSView *titleBarView = aWindow.titleBarView;
NSSize buttonSize = NSMakeSize(200.f, 100.f);
NSRect buttonFrame =
    NSMakeRect(NSMidX(titleBarView.bounds) - (buttonSize.width / 2.f),
               NSMidY(titleBarView.bounds) - (buttonSize.height / 2.f),
               buttonSize.width,
               buttonSize.height);
```

The previous code positioned the search box at the center of the title bar. What I want to do is position the search box at the left side of the title bar and if *"Maximize"* button of the application is clicked, I want the search box to remain at left. (not exact left. I want the left where there is a space between the search box and the left edge of the title bar).

Of course, I want to leave a space for the *"full screen"* arrows.

I'm not really familiar with Cocoa development (yet).
How to position my search box as I want?

Comment: Why don't you just modify the button frame to make it on the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to register to the notifications (NSWindowWillExitFullScreenNotification, NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification) and adjust the frame of the button accordingly.

For example

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(windowWillEnterFullScreen:)
                                                 name:NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(windowWillExitFullScreen:)
                                                 name:NSWindowWillExitFullScreenNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

And later

```
- (void)windowWillEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
 // set your button frame to the left
}


- (void)windowWillExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
 // set your button frame back to the centre
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Pure gold information! But, how to position my search button at the left? I'm used to IB but this is the first time I have to position the button programatically.

Comment: Well self.button.frame = NSRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.button.frame.size.width, self.button.frame.size.height) will place it to the very left, adjust X and Y accordingly.